# Spring Batch Writer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

For “READ-PROCESS-WRITE” process, it means “read” data from the resources (csv, xml or database), “process” it and “write” it to other resources (csv, xml and database). For example, a step may read data from a CSV file, process it and write it into the database

Is springBatch will support  to "Write" any message to a downstream through another webservice API(not to "Write" as CSV, XML and database)

Comment: Simple answer - Yes. Complicated answer - Share what you have come up with so far? and where you are struck and need help?

Comment: nothing like struck, i need to know is there a possibility in Spring Batch to Write(using Writer) to send some parameter values to another REST API not in CSV,XML and database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ItemWriter<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemWriter.html) and [`ItemStreamWriter<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemStreamWriter.html) are simple functional interfaces.  While the [Spring Batch](https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch) team have already implemented many [specific `ItemWriter` classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle/#itemWritersAppendix), you are free to implement your own given whatever business needs you have.

Basically, the `ItemWriter<T>` takes in a `List<T>` and writes out those items of type `T` as you choose to implement in the `write` method.

```java
void write(java.util.List<? extends T> items)
    throws java.lang.Exception
```

If you already have code written that performs the write operations you wish to perform with your `ItemWriter<T>`, then you may also be able to use the [`ItemWriterAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/adapter/ItemWriterAdapter.html) to create an `ItemWriter` that delegates to your existing code.